# DevTools windowOpen event not firing from Cef/CefSharp

Tags: cefsharp, chrome-devtools-protocol

I'm trying to get the [Page.windowOpen](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#event-windowOpen) event to fire when using [CefSharp](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp)

Here is the sample code

```f#
let browser = new ChromiumWebBrowser("https://www.google.com")
//removed code that waits for browser to load        
let client = browser.GetDevToolsClient()
client.Page.WindowOpen.Add(fun x -> Console.WriteLine(x.Url))
browser.ShowDevTools() //window.open('https://www.wikipedia.org') via console, event does not fire
client.Runtime.EvaluateAsync("window.open('https://www.wikipedia.org')") //event does not fire
```

The [windowOpen docs](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#event-windowOpen) are scant on detail, and I'm assuming this event should fire from the context of the page that is executing the `window.open()` js function

The window does physically open, but no event fires.

Where is the problem ?

- My implementation
- CefSharp
- Cef

Comment: You need to first call https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-enable

Comment: Brilliant, works perfectly. Shame the docs don't clearly state this requirement, I would never have found that without significant pain. Change you comment to an answer and I'll attribute the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you did not call [Page.enable](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Page/#method-enable). It is not well documented, but in order to have the **Page Domain** events fired (except for lifecycle ones as of now), you have to enable the domain.